# How can I use ParamSpec with method decorators?

Tags: python, typing, python-3.10

I was following the example [from PEP 0612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#motivation) (last one in the Motivation section) to create a decorator that can add default parameters to a function. The problem is, the example provided only works for functions but not methods, because `Concate` doesn't allow inserting `self` anywhere in the definition.

Consider this example, as an adaptation of the one in the PEP:

```
def with_request(f: Callable[Concatenate[Request, P], R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return f(*args, request=Request(), **kwargs)

    return inner


class Thing:
    @with_request
    def takes_int_str(self, request: Request, x: int, y: str) -> int:
        print(request)
        return x + 7


thing = Thing()
thing.takes_int_str(1, "A")  # Invalid self argument "Thing" to attribute function "takes_int_str" with type "Callable[[str, int, str], int]"
thing.takes_int_str("B", 2)  # Argument 2 to "takes_int_str" of "Thing" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

Both attempts raise a mypy error because `Request` doesn't match `self` as the first argument of the method, like `Concatenate` said. The problem is that `Concatenate` doesn't allow you to append `Request` to the end, so something like `Concatenate[P, Request]` won't work either.

This would be the ideal way to do this in my view, but it doesn't work because "The last parameter to Concatenate needs to be a ParamSpec".

```
def with_request(f: Callable[Concatenate[P, Request], R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    ...


class Thing:
    @with_request
    def takes_int_str(self, x: int, y: str, request: Request) -> int:
        ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is surprisingly little about this online. I was able to find [someone else's discussion of this over at `python/typing`'s Github](https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1040), which I distilled using your example.

The crux of this solution is [Callback `Protocol`s](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols), which are functionally equivalent to `Callable`, but additionally enable us to modify the return type of `__get__` (essentially removing the `self` parameter) as is done for standard methods.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Callable, Concatenate, Generic, ParamSpec, Protocol, TypeVar

from requests import Request

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R", covariant=True)


class Method(Protocol, Generic[P, R]):
    def __get__(self, instance: Any, owner: type | None = None) -> Callable[P, R]:
        ...

    def __call__(self_, self: Any, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        ...


def request_wrapper(f: Callable[Concatenate[Any, Request, P], R]) -> Method[P, R]:
    def inner(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return f(self, Request(), *args, **kwargs)

    return inner


class Thing:
    @request_wrapper
    def takes_int_str(self, request: Request, x: int, y: str) -> int:
        print(request)
        return x + 7


thing = Thing()
thing.takes_int_str(1, "a")
```

---

Since @Creris asked about the mypy error raised from the definition of `inner`, which is an apparent bug in mypy w/ `ParamSpec` and `Callback` `Protocol`s as of `mypy==0.991`, here is an alternate implementation with no errors:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

from requests import Request

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R", covariant=True)


def request_wrapper(f: Callable[Concatenate[Any, Request, P], R]) -> Callable[Concatenate[Any, P], R]:
    def inner(self: Any, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return f(self, Request(), *args, **kwargs)

    return inner


class Thing:
    @request_wrapper
    def takes_int_str(self, request: Request, x: int, y: str) -> int:
        print(request)
        return x + 7


thing = Thing()
thing.takes_int_str(1, "a")
```

Comment: I have a similar use case and this works great even on older versions, but there is once error that has to be ignored: `error: Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[Any, **P], R]", expected "Method[P, R]")` for the `return inner` line, because mypy does not think that the `inner` function implements the `Method` protocol. Do you think there is a way around that other than forcefully ignoring the error?

Comment: @Creris pyright doesn't give an error, so I would be inclined to believe that this is a bug in mypy. As far as I can tell, it does implement the `Method` `Protocol`. I think you can get around it though. I'll add an update.

Comment: I got around it with the good old fashioned `# type: ignore`, the code still runs properly and the rest of the code is also properly typed. Was just curious if you knew what the problem could be.